# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'csr_matrix'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I have a list containing sparse matrices:

```
 <1x248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

When I trying use sckit learn fit on it I get the error:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
classifier = GaussianNB()
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)



> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-79c5ac7b2aa7> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
      2 classifier = GaussianNB()
----> 3 classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    554                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    555                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 556                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    557 
    558         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[<1x248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <1x248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <1x248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 ...
 <1x248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <1x248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
 <1x248 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Try using `sparse.vstack` to join that list into one `csr`.Review the requirements for `fit` arguments.